# fetching data from the inner join query

Tags: php, mysql

hello please help me out regarding this query ,I am  fetching data from different table  The problem i am facing is that in the table there are similar colum name like employee  have and user has also name . The query work perfectly but i am wordering about how i can display this data as

```
$data["employee.name"]
$data["user.name"]
```

here is the query:

```
SELECT task.employee_id , task.user_id , task.service_id, user.name, 
       user.pic_path , employee.name ,employee.pic_path 
FROM task  
INNER JOIN employee ON employee.pno = task.employee_id  
INNER JOIN user ON user.pno = task.user_id 
INNER JOIN service ON service.service_id = task.service_id ";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT user.name AS username, employee.name AS employeename
```

You get the point.

Answer (score 2):

There are two steps:

1. You need to define a column alias for at least one of the two columns in the SQL statement:

   ```
   SELECT t.employee_id, 
          t.user_id, 
          t.service_id, 
          u.name AS user_name, 
          u.pic_path, 
          e.name AS employee_name,
          e.pic_path 
     FROM TASK t
     JOIN EMPLOYEE e ON e.pno = t.employee_id  
     JOIN USER u ON ur.pno = t.user_id 
     JOIN SERVICE s ON s.service_id = t.service_id
   ```
2. Then you need to update the PHP logic to use the column aliases:

   ```
   $empname = $data["employee_name"];
   $username = $data["user_name"];
   ```